# c# Merging two XMLs giving error

Tags: c#, .net, xml, c#-4.0, xml-parsing

I am trying to merge two XMLs with same structure but different data into one.

I am getting this error: `A node of type Document cannot be added to content.`

Below is my code

```
var productElements =
    testGroupProvider.GetTestGroup().ProductTests.Select(
        productTest => new XElement(xNamespace + "Product",
            new XElement(xNamespace + "ExternalId", productTest.ProductNameKey),
            new XElement(xNamespace + "Name", testGroupProvider.GetProductName(productTest)),
            new XElement(xNamespace + "ImageUrl", ChoiceBaseHostName + GetProductImageUrl(productTest, TargetDatabase))));

var root = new XDocument(
    new XElement(xNamespace + "Feed",
        new XAttribute("xmlns", xNamespace),
        new XAttribute("name", BVFeedsName),
        new XAttribute("incremental", "true"),
        new XAttribute("extractDate", DateTime.Now.ToString("o")),
        new XElement(xNamespace + "Categories",
            new XElement(xNamespace + "Category",
                new XElement(xNamespace + "ExternalId", testGroupProvider.GetProductGroup().Id),
                new XElement(xNamespace + "Name", testGroupProvider.GetProductGroup().Name),
        testGroupProvider.GetTestGroup().Name),
        new XElement(xNamespace + "Products", productElements)));


var filePath = @"D:\testXML\test.xml";
XElement xml = XElement.Load(filePath);
xml.Add(root);
xml.Save(filePath);
```

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong.

This is the XML structure in test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Feed xmlns="http://www.bazaarvoice.com/xs/PRR/ProductFeed/5.6" name="Choice" incremental="true" extractDate="2016-07-12T15:24:44.5732750+10:00">
  <Categories>
    <Category>
      <ExternalId>{09B3B4FB-F5CF-4522-BE96-4C4B535580C3}</ExternalId>
      <Name>Cereal and muesli</Name>
    </Category>
  </Categories>
  <Products>
    <Product>
      <ExternalId>coles-almond-hazelnut-macadamia-cluster-fusions</ExternalId>
      <Name>Coles Almond, Hazelnut &amp; Macadamia Cluster Fusions</Name>
       <ImageUrl></ImageUrl>
    </Product>
  </Products>
</Feed>
```

The second XML has the same structure with different products

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Feed xmlns="http://www.bazaarvoice.com/xs/PRR/ProductFeed/5.6" name="Choice" incremental="true" extractDate="2016-07-12T15:24:44.5732750+10:00">
  <Categories>
    <Category>
      <ExternalId>{12}</ExternalId>
      <Name>cat1</Name>
    </Category>
  </Categories>
  <Products>
    <Product>
      <ExternalId>Id</ExternalId>
      <Name>Ccoles</Name>
       <ImageUrl></ImageUrl>
    </Product>
  </Products>
</Feed>
```

I want to combine them like below

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Feed xmlns="http://www.bazaarvoice.com/xs/PRR/ProductFeed/5.6" name="Choice" incremental="true" extractDate="2016-07-12T15:24:44.5732750+10:00">
      <Categories>
        <Category>
          <ExternalId>{09B3B4FB-F5CF-4522-BE96-4C4B535580C3}</ExternalId>
          <Name>Cereal and muesli</Name>
        </Category>
         <Category>
          <ExternalId>{12}</ExternalId>
          <Name>cat1</Name>
        </Category>
      </Categories>
      <Products>
        <Product>
          <ExternalId>coles-almond-hazelnut-macadamia-cluster-fusions</ExternalId>
          <Name>Coles Almond, Hazelnut &amp; Macadamia Cluster Fusions</Name>
           <ImageUrl></ImageUrl>
        </Product>
        <Product>
          <ExternalId>Id</ExternalId>
          <Name>Ccoles</Name>
           <ImageUrl></ImageUrl>
        </Product>
      </Products>
    </Feed>
```

Comment: Clear enough - Document is topmost. `xml.Add(root)` fails.

Comment: Well the error message seems reasonably self-explanatory - an element can't contain a document. Perhaps you should create `root` as just the `XElement` instead? It doesn't help that we don't know what you're expecting to get out at the end, or what's in the existing file.

Comment: @Tommy   i have added the XML structure

Comment: But you haven't told us what you want the result to be. Currently your code is just trying to add one node to the existing document. If you mean you *actually* want to add all the categories from one document to the categories in the other, and ditto products, that's a different matter.

Comment: @JonSkeet please check now i have added the second xml and the combined xml as well

Comment: Your case is not just as simple as one `add`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A xml document must have *only one root*.

Working with the documents you attached, you can replace the `xml.Add(root);` with the following (i.e. it will add each node under one root to the other xml root)

```
foreach (var child in root.Root.Elements())
{
    xml.Element(child.Name.ToString()).Add(child.Nodes());
}
```

### Edit - A further generalization

You can generalize the above code using a `Merge` extension of 2 `XElement`s so that it reads as follows

```
foreach (var child in root.Elements())
{
    xml.Element(child.Name.ToString()).Merge(child, xNamespace + "ExternalId");
}
```

Having defined the extension

```
public static void Merge(this XElement root1, XElement root2, XName element_id)
{
    root1.Add(root2.Elements().Except(root1.Elements(), new MyComparer(element_id)));
}
```

with a xml comparer

```
public class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<XElement>
{
    private XName _element_id;
    public MyComparer(XName element_id)
    {
        _element_id = element_id;
    }
    public bool Equals(XElement x, XElement y)
    {
        return x.Element(_element_id).Value.Equals(y.Element(_element_id).Value);
    }
    public int GetHashCode(XElement el)
    {
        return el.Element(_element_id).Value.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Select correct nodes to add and correct nodes to be added.

```
var filePath = @"D:\testXML\test.xml";
XElement xml = XElement.Load(filePath);

var xmlCategories = xml.Descendants("Categories").First();
var rootCategories = root.Descendants("Category");
xmlCategories.Add(rootCategories);

var xmlProducts = xml.Descendants("Products").First();
var rootProducts = root.Descendants("Product");
xmlProducts.Add(rootProducts);

xml.Save(filePath);
```

Be crystal clear what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME1 = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        const string FILENAME2 = @"c:\temp\test2.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(FILENAME1);
            XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Load(FILENAME2);

            XElement category1 = doc1.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Categories").FirstOrDefault();
            XElement category2 = doc2.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Categories").FirstOrDefault();
            category1.Add(category2.Descendants());


            XElement product1 = doc1.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Products").FirstOrDefault();
            XElement product2 = doc2.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Products").FirstOrDefault();
            product1.Add(product2.Descendants());
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, sorry about the VB

```
    'second is The second XML has the same structure with different products

    Dim combined As XElement = New XElement(test) 'create copy of test.xml
    combined.<Categories>.LastOrDefault.Add(second.<Categories>.Elements)
    combined.<Products>.LastOrDefault.Add(second.<Products>.Elements)
```

or

```
    'if test can be used to combine then

    test.<Categories>.LastOrDefault.Add(second.<Categories>.Elements)
    test.<Products>.LastOrDefault.Add(second.<Products>.Elements)
```

The result is

```
<Feed name="Choice" incremental="true" extractDate="2016-07-12T15:24:44.5732750+10:00" xmlns="http://www.bazaarvoice.com/xs/PRR/ProductFeed/5.6">
  <Categories>
    <Category>
      <ExternalId>{09B3B4FB-F5CF-4522-BE96-4C4B535580C3}</ExternalId>
      <Name>Cereal and muesli</Name>
    </Category>
    <Category>
      <ExternalId>{12}</ExternalId>
      <Name>cat1</Name>
    </Category>
  </Categories>
  <Products>
    <Product>
      <ExternalId>coles-almond-hazelnut-macadamia-cluster-fusions</ExternalId>
      <Name>Coles Almond, Hazelnut &amp; Macadamia Cluster Fusions</Name>
      <ImageUrl></ImageUrl>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <ExternalId>Id</ExternalId>
      <Name>Ccoles</Name>
      <ImageUrl></ImageUrl>
    </Product>
  </Products>
</Feed>
```

The test data I used is

```
    Dim test As XElement =
        <Feed xmlns="http://www.bazaarvoice.com/xs/PRR/ProductFeed/5.6" name="Choice" incremental="true" extractDate="2016-07-12T15:24:44.5732750+10:00">
            <Categories>
                <Category>
                    <ExternalId>{09B3B4FB-F5CF-4522-BE96-4C4B535580C3}</ExternalId>
                    <Name>Cereal and muesli</Name>
                </Category>
            </Categories>
            <Products>
                <Product>
                    <ExternalId>coles-almond-hazelnut-macadamia-cluster-fusions</ExternalId>
                    <Name>Coles Almond, Hazelnut &amp; Macadamia Cluster Fusions</Name>
                    <ImageUrl></ImageUrl>
                </Product>
            </Products>
        </Feed>

    Dim second As XElement =
        <Feed xmlns="http://www.bazaarvoice.com/xs/PRR/ProductFeed/5.6" name="Choice" incremental="true" extractDate="2016-07-12T15:24:44.5732750+10:00">
            <Categories>
                <Category>
                    <ExternalId>{12}</ExternalId>
                    <Name>cat1</Name>
                </Category>
            </Categories>
            <Products>
                <Product>
                    <ExternalId>Id</ExternalId>
                    <Name>Ccoles</Name>
                    <ImageUrl></ImageUrl>
                </Product>
            </Products>
        </Feed>
```

The XElements can be loaded like this

```
    test = XElement.Load("PATH")
    second = XElement.Load("second PATH")
```

and saved like this

```
    test.Save("PATH")
    second.Save("second PATH")
    combined.Save("combined PATH")
```